# JWT::InvalidIatError at /user/auth/google_oauth2/callback Invalid iat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, google-oauth, omniauth

I get this error when I try to log in using Google oauth2 locally. Googling the error doesn't give me any indication. On Heroku I don't have any issues

This is my omniauth controller function for google:

```
  def google_oauth2
      # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
      @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

      if @user.persisted? # Check if the user exits
        sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
        # flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Google"
      else
        session["devise.google_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"].except('extra')
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
      end
  end
```

This is the server log output:

```
Started GET "/user/auth/google_oauth2" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-10-04 17:11:23 -0400
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
I, [2015-10-04T17:11:23.278558 #8203]  INFO -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Request phase initiated.


Started GET "/user/auth/google_oauth2/callback?state=7080deaf5a52603044da3856898c08a89722f57e4dc9e75d&code=4/vWA-kcX2_P8JF6i10VIMRtYO81crG5vyPMRyknGs3q4" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-10-04 17:11:26 -0400
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
I, [2015-10-04T17:11:26.065521 #8203]  INFO -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Callback phase initiated.

JWT::InvalidIatError - Invalid iat:
  jwt (1.5.1) lib/jwt.rb:170:in `decode'
  omniauth-google-oauth2 (0.2.7) lib/omniauth/strategies/google_oauth2.rb:63:in `block in <class:GoogleOauth2>'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:105:in `block in compile_stack'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:104:in `compile_stack'
  (eval):7:in `extra_stack'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:329:in `extra'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:336:in `auth_hash'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:361:in `callback_phase'
  omniauth-oauth2 (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb:79:in `callback_phase'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:227:in `callback_call'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:184:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  bullet (4.14.7) lib/bullet/rack.rb:12:in `call'
  meta_request (0.3.4) lib/meta_request/middlewares/app_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
  meta_request (0.3.4) lib/meta_request/middlewares/meta_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
  rails-dev-boost (0.3.0) lib/rails_development_boost/async.rb:14:in `call'
  jquery-fileupload-rails (0.4.6) lib/jquery/fileupload/rails/middleware.rb:14:in `_call'
  jquery-fileupload-rails (0.4.6) lib/jquery/fileupload/rails/middleware.rb:10:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  remotipart (1.2.1) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  rack-contrib (1.4.0) lib/rack/contrib/response_headers.rb:17:in `call'
  meta_request (0.3.4) lib/meta_request/middlewares/headers.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  rack-mini-profiler (0.9.7) lib/mini_profiler/profiler.rb:276:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/server.rb:507:in `handle_request'
  puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/server.rb:375:in `process_client'
  puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/server.rb:262:in `block in run'
  puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is actually the root of your issue, but it looks like you have a server running on a virtual machine and you're trying to go through the OAuth flow in the browser of your host machine. I don't think this will work because Google disallows OAuth clients with internal IP addresses (with the exception of localhost/127.0.0.1), so you instead need to do one of the following:

1. Use the browser in your VM (if possible)
2. Run the server in your host machine (if possible)
3. Use port-forwarding to forward the server port on your VM to a port on your host machine

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Recently [google_oauth2](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2) released a way where we can ByPass JWT decoding.

use option *:skip_jwt => true* in file where you have configured OmniAuth.

```
use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"],ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"], skip_jwt: true
end
```

For More details check [Fix Steps By Gem Author](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/issues/197)

Comment: Where and into which document does `:skip_jwt => true` go?

Comment: use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"], ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"], skip_jwt: true
end

Comment: @jvenezia hey! there did not tried skipping because it served the purpose for me, and now on updating app/gem it got fixed for me without it. Though, when i got stucked on it dirt my hands with something called jwt_leeway, try reading this on there doc. May be it helpful for you.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 6):

`skip_jwt: true` is not always the best way to do that. The problem seems to lie in the hardware clock of my server in this case. It was off by 72 seconds in my case and if i recall by default JWT allows 60 seconds. You can check that and fix it by doing the following.

```
sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com


setup cronjob to check every hour and fix it


sudo nano /etc/cron.hourly/ntpdate


add

#! /bin/sh

ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com

save file and change permissions


sudo chmod +x /etc/cron.hourly/ntpdate
```

Answer (score 3):

based on the answer by @imsinu9 :

```
use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"], ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"], skip_jwt: true
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Combine with other params if any

```
provider :google_oauth2, ENV['GOOGLE_KEY'],   ENV['GOOGLE_SECRET'], { access_type: 'online', skip_jwt: true }
```